# Recursively get palindrome of n

Tags: java, recursion

A user enters n and the recursive method returns the palindrome of n.

For example:

- For `n = 3` method prints: `3`
- For `n = 13` method prints: `1331`
- For `n = 133` method prints: `133331`

Basically, method reverses `n` and then adds it to the original `n`.

I know how to print reversed n, but I am having trouble with saving the reversed number. How could I upgrade my code below to return n+reversed n(1331)?

```
public class test {
    public static void palindrome(int n) {
        if (n < 10) {
            System.out.print(n);
            return;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(n % 10);
            palindrom(n/10);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        palindrome(13);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. If the input is `133`, the expected result should be `133331` or `1331`?

Comment: The result should be 133331

Comment: And, for input `3`, the result should be `3` or `33`? You should edit the question and make it clear.

Comment: Are you restricted to integers only for the output of `palindrom()`?

Comment: Are you allowed to convert it to a String first? Doing that with strings will be easier

Comment: Sounds like your homework wants to teach you something about Queues and Stacks, check it out

Comment: This does indeed feel like homework. Show us what you have tried out first.

Comment: Or it might be job application question. They ask recursive questions in job applications.

Comment: @Thracian, if it's a job application question, then I guess they're going to be limited to integers only.

Comment: You are missing a `System.out.print(n % 10);` after `palindrom(n/10);`. Also a `System.out.print(n);` after `System.out.print(n);` is missing.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais, i'm just guessing. It's probably homework or job application question.

Comment: It is for homework. I have managed to print the reversed n, but I am having trouble with adding reversed n to the original n in order to get 1331.

Comment: @Piki, why not just print `n` first the the reversed `n`? Unless of course you have other requirements.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais Method must return an int.

Comment: @Piki, what other things have you tried?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais: SO questions judgment should be NEVER based whether it's a homework or not since it meets the criteria for a valid question at all. OP showed his attempt through a piece of code. It's not your duty to help but your will.

Comment: @Nikolas, that, I agree. However, I was gauging whether this would fall under spoonfeeding, which I discourage. My query on if he has attempted something else was a factor to help me decide whether I would spoonfeeding OP or not.

Comment: @Nikolas, but I have to say, this is pretty interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code can solve your problem:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(palindrome(133));
}

private static int palindrome (int n){
     return palindrome(n,n);
}

private static int palindrome( int n, int r ){
    if(r==0)
        return n;
    return palindrome(n*10+r%10,r/10);
}
```

You can check it out [here](http://tpcg.io/L7oB2m) .

Answer (score 1):

It's a very nice question. I am not sure whether a single recursive function is possible, but I have found a solution using the indirect recursion (correct me if I am wrong). The problem is that only at the first iteration is needed to print the whole number and then print the digits one by one backward.

You call it the same:

```
palindrome(3); // results in 3
palindrome(13); // results in 1331
palindrome(133); // results in 133331
palindrome(1330); // results in 13300331
```

Here is the code.

```
public static void palindrome(int n) {
    palindrom(n, 0);
    System.out.println();
}

private static void palindrome(int n, int iteration) {
    int number = n;
    if (n < 10) {
        System.out.print(n);
        return;
    } else {
       if (iteration == 0) {
            System.out.print(n);
        }
        int reverse = n%10;
        System.out.print(reverse);
        iteration++;
        palindrom(n/10, iteration);
    }
}
```

Btw. It's called palindrom**e**, so I correct the names in your code and the mine one as well.

Comment: Sorry about that, in my mother's tongue it is palindrom without the e.

Answer (score -1):

You're having trouble solving the problem because it isn't a recursion problem. It's just a looping one. The string is an array and the solution is to simply reverse it. So the solution is to use recursion to do math on an array index.

Recursion has nothing to do with looping. Passing a function to itself as a parameter doesn't create recursion.

There's probably a recursive solution to determining if a word is a palindrome. You can see how much more complicated it would be to determine if any word is a palindrome.

**[Edited 5-21-18: trying to clarify my answer]**

The problem is recursion is a very high-level concept so it's very hard to teach. The person that created this question doesn't understand recursion so they've made a mistake. It's like requiring the use of a two-dimensional array to solve this same question. It's incorrect on many profound levels.

I hadn't come across the palindrome example before. It was always towers of hanoi. So I didn't instantly recognize it. Determining if a word or phrase is a palindrome is the correct question.

Here's the determining if a phrase is a palindrome problem is being used in an intro to comp sci lecture (at 29 minutes): [MIT Opencourseware on Youtube](https://youtu.be/WPSeyjX1-4s?t=29m8s)

Comment: But he is required to use **recursion** instead of looping to create the palindrome.

Comment: Yes, I understand what the question says but it doesn't make sense. The question is incorrect so the solutions won't be recursion.

Comment: Why doesn't it makes sense and what makes it incorrect?